# is it necessary to import vue in all components? Nuxt and typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Currently I have integrated typescript to nuxt, as indicated in the documentation: https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/es/guide/setup/

but I have the following doubt: in the components you should always `import vue from "vue"` and `export default Vue.extend ({});` In the documentation I see that they carry out the example with 1 component (https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/es/cookbook/components) but in my case I have the doubt if I really should add them to all the components or in what way can I do this global.

I thought that the configuration that I have in my `types/vue-shim.d.ts` file did this for me, but then I have the concept wrong.

`vue-shim.d.ts`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

Before adding typescript to nuxt, my components were like this:

```html
<script>
import comp from "../component.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    comp
  },
  data() {
    return {
      createUser: true,
      params: {
        rol_id: 0,
        post_url: "",
        update_url: ""
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.params.post_url = this.$config.routePrefix + "/agency/";
    this.params.update_url = this.$config.routePrefix + "/agency/";
    if (this.$route.params.uuid !== undefined) {
      this.createUser = false;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchForms() {}
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not absolutely necessary to import `vue` in all components.

As stated in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage), `Vue.extend` is only needed to enable type inference in your TypeScript IDE. For instance, it lets TypeScript infer the type of `this.params` in `mounted()` based on the declaration of `params` in `data()`.

`Vue.extend` doesn't add any functionality, so your component would run the same with or without `Vue.extend`. However, to get the full benefit of using TypeScript, you *should* use `Vue.extend` in your components.

Comment: I understand, but how could I add that in Visual Studio Code? Since I get errors like 'Property 'value' does not exist on type, that is, the ones I have added in the `data () {return {value: ''}}`

Comment: To avoid those errors, you need to import `vue` in your components, and use `Vue.extend()`.

Comment: Is there any way to configure this globally so as not to add in each component?

Comment: No, that's currently not possible.